# Brightcove Player Issue on IOS

Tags: ios, brightcove

I am working on iPhone application where i have included bright cove SDK to play video. I am able to play video but found letter boxing issue around sides of player view(black space on top and side bar). How can i avoid letterboxing around UIView corners? it would be great if you can provide any example or any sample code.I am attaching screenshot for player as well.

[image]

Comment: don't get it where is a view corner

Comment: wild guess :: `view.masksToBound = NO?`

Comment: or do you mean you want it fullscreen? than add it to a fullscreen view .. maybe even the window.. don't know

Comment: please edit the question

Comment: i have edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the ratio of the video from the video properties:

```
video.properties[kBCOVCatalogJSONKeyFLVFullLength][@"frameWidth"];
video.properties[kBCOVCatalogJSONKeyFLVFullLength][@"frameHeight"];
```

Then adjust the size of your video player view (`playbackController.view`) to suit the required height. This may involve the view being wider than its parent and clipping of the left and right sides, but will achieve the desired result.